# Data Loader behavior with addError()

Tags: trigger, data-loader

I have a `before update` trigger on `User` object which checks for certain User fields. If that field matches a condition I am supposed to skip the update of that user record, else make some field updates on that record. I achieved this using `addError()` method.

```
newUser.addError('Skipping non-company employees');
```

When I use data loader to update multiple  records, the `before update` trigger is executing multiple times. For example, if I have 4 records in my CSV file with one record to be skipped and 3 different email updates to be made on other 3 records, the individuals with the updated email IDs are getting 3 emails each for verifying the email ID change. This means my before update trigger is fired multiple times. When I do not have any records to be skipped with `addError()`, this the users get only one verification email, as expected.

This is very strange. I have referred [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093CKIAY) post, but the explanation given should not make field updates multiple times as per my knowledge.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So you are trying to import a sheet which contains user data, and when the user is not on the company, you don't do whatever you are doing on the trigger? That's the logic?

Comment: Correct @RenatoOliveira

Comment: Have you considered just not using `addError` at all? I mean, just bypass the users you don't need to run your code on. Since you are running on `before update` you can easily copy the changed fields from the existing record on the database, which is available on `Trigger.old` as a list and `Trigger.oldMap` as a map of Id to User.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira This is what I have in my mind as the last resort if I din't get any solution.

Comment: I'll post that as an answer then, in case you really don't find another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider not using `addError` at all. Just bypass the users you don't need to run your code on: since you are running a trigger on `before update` you can easily copy the changed fields form the existing record on the database, which are available on `Trigger.old` and `Trigger.oldMap` as both list and map of Id to User.

Answer (score 0):

If you make updates to a batch of records through the API or using apex with `allOrNone` set to false, and a trigger uses `addError` on some of the records within a batch, Salesforce will [rollback the changes that occurred within the trigger, and then call the trigger again with the records that did not have errors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_bulk_exceptions.htm).

Note that if the same trigger operates in both a `before` and `after` context, and `addError` is used in the `before` context, the trigger will be called with the `after` context on the non-error records before rolling back, and then calling trigger again (in both the `before` and `after` contexts).